# Hadoop read input split multiple times

Tags: input, hadoop, split, iteration, regression

I need to *iterate* over the input splits *more than once*. 
The reason I need this is beyond the scope of this question. Let's suppose I just need it (A brief explanation would be that I need to use the input split more than once to populate a data structure and the split might be large enough so that it cannot be accommodated in memory after the first iteration through it)

I suppose I could do a number of tricks  such as extending the `FileInputFormat` and the `RecordReader` to serve the split a number of times but I was wondering if there is any "standard" way of doing it in Hadoop. 
I'm not aware of any standard method of achieving this in Hadoop but probably I missed something.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do to and with that data structure during one of the multiple passes through the splits? (Lookup, update, etc.)

Have you tried parallel-izig that action with some earlier hadoop jobs, perhaps even some pig scripts?

Comment: To be more precise I'm building a regression tree out of the data in the split. Building a regression tree out of data which doesn't reside in memory means passing multiple times through the data.

I want to do it locally, only in the map side of only one MR job.
Each mapper learns one tree!